# tag form-w-4 and w4 be synonyms

Tags: discussion, support, tag-synonyms

I am new to site, but feel that

https://money.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

should show 
https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-w-4 
 and
https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/w4

be same

Answer (score 3):

I appreciated the alert. Plain W4 has no usage and will 'fall off' the system very soon. If there were questions on both tags, we would merge and assign a synonym.

Comment: Thanks, i am learning

Comment: No kidding. I'm a mod, and I did not know all the rules of tags until you asked this. We both learned something new.

Comment: Somebody added the w4 tag to a question last week. I removed it and put the correct tag on the question.